# JIT. Best way serialize to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, thejit

I need to create a custom json for [the jit](http://thejit.org/) library. Should I use additional C# logic or somehow to extend JsonSerializer. Json should be like this -->

```
var json = {
    "children": [
 {
     "children": [
     {
         "children": [],
         "data": {
             "playcount": "276",
             "$color": "#8E7032",
             "image": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/11403219.jpg",
             "$area": 276
         },
         "id": "album-Thirteenth Step",
         "name": "Thirteenth Step"
     }
}]
```

}

Comment: have you tried this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: yes but I need more custom json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
public void Test()
{
    Node root = new Node();
    Node child = new Node();
    Data data = new Data() { Area = 276, Color = "#8E7032", PlayCount = "276", Image = "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/300x300/11403219.jpg" };
    Node grandChild = new Node() { Id = "album-Thirteenth Step", Name = "Thirteenth Step", Data = data };

    root.Children.Add(child);
    child.Children.Add(grandChild);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                              root, 
                              new JsonSerializerSettings() {  
                                  NullValueHandling= NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                                  Formatting= Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
                              });
}

public class Node
{
    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data;

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name;
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("playcount")]
    public string PlayCount;

    [JsonProperty("$color")]
    public string Color;

    [JsonProperty("image")]
    public string Image;

    [JsonProperty("$area")]
    public int Area;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you though about Json.net?

http://json.codeplex.com/

At least you will have a good level of customization room + a better serializer

Answer (score 1):

[json](http://json.codeplex.com/) - the best tool to work with json

Comment: Why is it "the best"? Can you provide some context? Or is it best for *all* use cases?

Comment: iwein, Where did you find my own website?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack.Text is the fastest one.

For benchmarks: http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/